# how to plot multiple lines while reading x and y from files in a for loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a for loop in which for every input file I read x and y from the file and save them as I want in separate lists  and then plot a graph. Now I want to plot all the x-y of all files in just one plot . The problem is that I'm reading x and y from my files in a for loop so I have to plot them and then go to the next file , otherwise I will lose x and y and I don't want to save them in another file and then plot them together. Are there any suggestions? I would appreciate any advice as it's the first time I'm using matplotlib and I'm new to python.

```
for f in os.listdir(Source):
x=[]
y=[]
file_name= f
print 'Processing file : ' + str (file_name)
pkl_file = open( os.path.join(Source,f) , 'rb' )
List=pickle.load(pkl_file)
pkl_file.close()
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(i[0],'%Y-%m-%d')for i in List ]
y = [i[1] for i in List]
maxRange=max(y)

if not maxRange >= 5 :
    print 'The word #' +str(file_name[0]) + ' has a frequency of ' +str(maxRange) + '.'
else :
    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.ylim(0,maxRange)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
    plt.plot(x, y , 'm')
    plt.xlabel('Time')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    fig.savefig("Plots/"+ file_name[0] + '.pdf' )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There ya go. Took the liberty of offering a few more recommendations, though not all.

```
fig = plt.figure()
maxRange = 0
for file_name in os.listdir(source):
    print 'Processing file : ' + str(file_name)
    with open(os.path.join(source,file_name), 'rb') as pkl_file:
        lst = pickle.load(pkl_file)
    x,y = zip(*[(dt.datetime.strptime(x_i,'%Y-%m-%d'), y_i) for (x_i, y_i) in lst])
    if max(y) < 5 :
        print 'The word #' +str(file_name[0]) + ' has a frequency of ' +str(maxRange) + '.'
    else :
        maxRange=max(maxRange, max(y))
        plt.plot(x, y , 'm')
plt.ylim(0,maxRange)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
fig.savefig("Plots/allfiles.pdf")
```

Comment: thank you so much , it sounds really good. I'm trying to make it run but I'm getting some invalid syntax error near the if not max(y) , I'm trying to figure out what's the problem as soon as I run it , I will give you feedback.

Comment: @Singu Missed a closing bracket. try now.

Comment: Thank you so much. it works! but is there any way that I can have different colors in order to recognize each line is for which word?

Comment: @Singu take a look at [colormaps](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCcQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmatplotlib.org%2Fapi%2Fcolors_api.html&ei=gF8LVNGLCsL-ygPouoGgBg&usg=AFQjCNErMCR324oIPQltN_hwniq9aAfaGA&sig2=eMHJdK-88Bhu5KhomaamHw).